# Why is my code for Codingbat String-2 EndOther not working?

Tags: java, string

I won't lie, this is sort of homework for my AP Computer Science class. But I talked to my teacher, and he couldn't figure it out either.

So I'm doing the Java CodingBat problem String-2 endOther [here](http://codingbat.com/prob/p126880), and I don't know why my code isn't working properly.

The goal of the challenge is to determine if one string appears at the very end of the other string. If so, return true, otherwise return false.

Example: If the strings were "Hiabc" and "abc", it would return true, but "Hiabcx" and "bc" would return false because "bc" isn't at the end.
Note: Case does not matter.

My code works for all of the examples that it runs through, except for "other tests". I might have been able to figure out how to fix it, except I don't know what "other tests" it ran. So any help on this? Here's my code:

```
public boolean endOther(String a, String b) {
    a = a.toLowerCase();
    b = b.toLowerCase();
    if (a.contains(b) && a.indexOf(b) == a.length() - b.length()) {
        return true;
    } else if (b.contains(a) && b.indexOf(a) == b.length() - a.length()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Two things.  Firstly, I'm not sure how you think we can help you if you don't have the failing test case.  Secondly, why not use the `endsWith` method on your String?

Comment: @JoeC:  You can run the tests yourself on CodingBat; the test fails in a nondescript "other" box which can be notoriously frustrating to figure out.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of "edge case"; namely, what happens if your input(s) are null or blank, but the question doesn't specify behavior for that.

Comment: @Makoto I have tried putting in blank checks, and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Yes, I did as well and that didn't change anything.  Seemed like it'd be a quick win on that regard.  Hmm.

Comment: @JoeC I was not aware of that method. I tried it and it works, however I would still like to know what I could do to fix this, so that I learn what I did wrong, or forgot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that an answer to this question has already been posted, but as far as your original code goes, I think I have an idea of what went wrong. 
If the one of the "other tests" used a string such as "abc" and was compared with a string that had more than one occurrence of "abc" such as "Hiabcabc", then your code would fail even though "abc" is at the end of "Hiabcabc".
The reason this happens is that `indexOf()` looks for the *first* occurrence of the parameter and returns the index of it. This would result in false negatives in tests that contained more than one occurrence of the smaller string.

Using `substring()` is probably the best solution to this problem as it would allow you to look specifically at the end of the string, however if you wanted to modify your code as little as possible, you could use `lastIndexOf()` as an alternative to `indexOf()`. This would result in your code passing all of the tests.

Here's your modified code:

```
public boolean endOther(String a, String b) {
  a = a.toLowerCase();
  b = b.toLowerCase();
  if (a.contains(b) && a.lastIndexOf(b) == a.length() - b.length()) {
    return true;
  } else if (b.contains(a) && b.lastIndexOf(a) == b.length() - a.length()) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false; 
  }
}
```

And here's the Oracle docs page on `indexOf()` in case you want to do some more reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)

Comment: I was aware of the fact that `indexOf()` returns the first found index, I just kind of forgot that they might have put the same string in the other string twice. However, I did not know that `lastIndexOf()` existed, so I tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is ancient but maybe someone will need this information. Here is my solution to String-2 > endOther

```
public boolean endOther(String a, String b) {
  a = a.toLowerCase();
  b = b.toLowerCase();
  if ((a.endsWith(b)) || (b.endsWith(a))) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My gut feeling is that they want you to use `substring`.  The reason for this is simple:  it doesn't matter where else the pattern occurs in either string, so long as it's at the *final* position(s) of that string.

You also shouldn't (in practice) manipulate the parameters you pass in, since that may trip you up later.  Adding `final` to your param list will prevent you from doing so, just in case you accidentally think that it's doing something you don't.

Lastly, you don't need to convert both strings to lower case at all; there is a method called `equalsIgnoreCase` which works *just fine* for this case.

To solve the problem, I've abstracted out a different method to accomplish the main comparison.  The logic in the main method only determines which string goes where (since the longer string may be on the right).  Below is my solution, which passes *all* of the tests.

```
public boolean endOther(final String a, final String b) {
    if (a.length() >= b.length()) {
        return endOtherHelper(a, b);
    } else {
        return endOtherHelper(b, a);
    }
}

private boolean endOtherHelper(final String longStr, final String shortStr) {
    return longStr.substring(longStr.length() - shortStr.length()).equalsIgnoreCase(shortStr);
}
```

Comment: The reason that I didn't use the `equalsIgnoreCase` method was because I wasn't actually checking for any String equality. And again, this solution does work (again relating to using the `String.endsWith` method), but do you know why my code didn't? Personally I would rather it be explained to me why what I wrote didn't work and how to fix it rather than being given an alternate solution. If I can't find out why, I may end up using the `endsWith` method, but I would ideally like to just be able to fix my current code.

Comment: @RoboticPlayer:  That's likely just the thing.  I found no faults with your code aside from persnickety ones like mutating your parameters, but the actual test(s) may have come from either inspecting your use of methods or the number of calls you made to `String` methods.  In reality, your code is probably fine, and the tests that CodingBat are using are a bit strange.  I wouldn't read too much into it here, but the solution I authored is more of a straightforward approach anyway, as long as you get the slices of it right.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code, perhaps you will understand the mistakes:

```
public boolean endOther(String a, String b) {
  if(a.length() < b.length())
    return b.toLowerCase().substring(b.length()-a.length()).equals(a.toLowerCase());
  else
    return a.toLowerCase().substring(a.length()-b.length()).equals(b.toLowerCase());
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.